# Do I have to populate tm_gmtoff and tm_zone? and, Which function shall I use mktime or gmtime to get a timezone-less datetime in C?

Tags: c, datetime, time, timezone, c89

I am trying to code a function which populates a `struct tm` from year, month, day, hour and minutes values.

The application deals with no time zone information, i.e., we assume that the input data time zone matches with the application and user time zone.

I have tried this:

```c
void timeCreate(struct tm* pTm1, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute) {

    pTm1->tm_year = year - 1900;
    pTm1->tm_mon = month - 1;
    pTm1->tm_mday = day;
    pTm1->tm_hour = hour;
    pTm1->tm_min = minute;
    pTm1->tm_sec = 0;
    pTm1->tm_isdst = -1;
    mktime(pTm1);

}
```

If I don't do anything else, I get the CET time set by mktime (CET is my local timezone) and it seems that mktime changes the time and date, so it is no longer 2014/01/01 00:00 but the day before.

If I do this:

```
    pTm1->tm_gmtoff = 0;
    pTm1->tm_zone = "UTC";
```

Then I do not get any correction.

I have also seen the function `gmtime()` instead of `mktime()`. Which would be the "right" way of setting up this struct?

Also I get a random value for `tm_wday`, can that value be calculated automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mktime` only works with local time, and its behavior is constrained by the specification so that it *cannot* examine any nonstandard fields of `struct tm` like `tm_gmtoff`. And `gmtime` is not an analog of `mktime` but of `localtime` - it converts in the opposite direction. If you want a normalization/conversion of broken-down UTC time in `struct tm` format to `time_t`, you need to either use the nonstandard but widely available `timegm` function, or write it out yourself. Thankfully POSIX [exactly specifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_16) the formula:

```
tm_sec + tm_min*60 + tm_hour*3600 + tm_yday*86400 +
    (tm_year-70)*31536000 + ((tm_year-69)/4)*86400 -
    ((tm_year-1)/100)*86400 + ((tm_year+299)/400)*86400
```

Note that if copied as written to C code, this is full of integer overflows, so some type promotions or other fixes need to be introduced to make it valid.

If you need the normalization aspect `timegm` also performs, but need it done portably without depending on the nonportable `timegm`, you can just call `gmtime_r` after using the above formula to invert it and get a normalized result.

Comment: "it cannot examine any nonstandard fields of struct tm like tm_gmtoff"  is questionable.  The C spec does have "The original values of the tm_wday and tm_yday components of the
structure are ignored, and the original values of the other components are not  restricted to the ranges indicated above.".  I see no support for the _cannot examine any nonstandard fields_ claim.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: The behavior of the function is fully specified for a program that just sets up the `struct tm` members that are specified and leaves any other implementation defined ones uninitialized. Thereby the result cannot be a function (in a mathematical sense) of such additional members. Mechanically it could "examine" them but it can't set the standard fields differently from what it's specified to do based on their contents.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to populate `tm_gmtoff` and `tm_zone`?
> Which would be the "right" way of setting up this struct?

For portable code, yes.

The C spec has

"The tm structure shall contain **at least** the following members, in any order." (C spec) --> `struct tm` has *at least* the following 9 members:

```
int tm_sec;
int tm_min;
int tm_hour;
int tm_mday;
int tm_mon;
int tm_year; 
int tm_wday;
int tm_yday;
int tm_isdst;
```

And may include others like `tm_gmtoff`, `tm_zone`, `tm_msec`, etc.

> The `mktime` function converts the broken-down time, expressed as local time, in the structure pointed to by `timeptr` into a calendar time value with the same encoding as that of the values returned by the `time` function. The original values of the `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` components of the structure are ignored, and the original values of the **other components** are not restricted to the ranges indicated above. ...
> ... On successful completion, the values of the `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` components of the structure are set appropriately, and the **other components** are set to represent the specified calendar time, but with their values forced to the ranges indicated above; the final value of `tm_mday` is not set until `tm_mon` and `tm_year` are determined.
> C17dr § 7.27.2.3 2

Since `mktime()` is only specified to ignore `tm_wday` and `tm_yday`, **all other members may contribute to the result**.  There is no C spec that limits the result to 7 of the above required members.

Good programing practice would zero out all members not explicitly initialized/assigned before calling `mktime()`.

```
void timeCreate(struct tm* pTm1, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute) {
  memset(pTm1, 0, sizeof *pTm1);  // Zero all members.
  pTm1->tm_year = year - 1900;
  pTm1->tm_mon = month - 1;
  pTm1->tm_mday = day;
  pTm1->tm_hour = hour;
  pTm1->tm_min = minute;
  pTm1->tm_sec = 0;
  pTm1->tm_isdst = -1;
  mktime(pTm1);
  // recommend to return the result of mktime() so caller can ID invalid timestamps.
}
```

If you code is used on a sub-set of platforms, it may get away without such zeroing assignments.